# Local notification "schedule" and "trigger" methods are executing multiple times

Tags: cordova, notifications, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins, localnotification

Hi I'm new on ionic and I'm using (katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications), I have a problem and I don't know what is happening.

When I click in a link, I'm generating a new notification. But I don't know for what when I click for the second time in the notification, the alert inside of "schedule" and "trigger" is executed two times, and when I click for the third time in the notification, the alert inside of "schedule" and "trigger" is executed three times, and so..

This is my code, it's very simple:

```
$scope.addNotification = function (){


    var idaudio = Math.round(Math.random() * 10000);
    var date = Date.now();

    cordova.plugins.notification.local.schedule({
        id: idaudio,
        title: 'Remember',
        text: 'New Remember',
        at: date

    });


    cordova.plugins.notification.local.on("schedule", function(notification){
        alert("scheduled: " + notification.id);
    });


    cordova.plugins.notification.local.on('trigger', function (notification){
        alert("trigger" + notification.id)
    });
}
```

I need that when I click in a notification only one alert print the related notification id.

Can anyone help me please?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Welcome to stackoverflow =)

With your code, **every time** you **click** to add a notification, you are **adding event handlers** for "schedule" and "trigger" events.

For example, the first time you **click** on **addNotification**, cordova.plugins.notification.local.on("schedule") will **register** and event handler to "**functionA**". The **second time** you click it, another event will be registered to "**functionB**", and so on. functionA, functionB,...will **all be called** when the "schedule" event is fired.

**Solution**, move your event handling code outside of the function.

```
$scope.addNotification = function (){
    var idaudio = Math.round(Math.random() * 10000);
    var date = Date.now();

    cordova.plugins.notification.local.schedule({
        id: idaudio,
        title: 'Remember',
        text: 'New Remember',
        at: date

    });

}

//this should only be registered once    
$scope.$on('$cordovaLocalNotification:schedule',function(notification) {
    alert("scheduled: " + notification.id);
});

//this should only be registered once    
$scope.$on('$cordovaLocalNotification:trigger',function(notification) {
    alert("triggered: " + notification.id);
});
```

//////notification.id must be set globally, otherwise it is gonna show as undefined.

Comment: Really a great answer. It helped me to solve the problem and save a lot of hours. It seemed like some modification is needed on the onSchedule and onTrigger functions. Already suggested according to my working ones. Thanks a lot for your valuable answer. :)

Comment: Can you please give solution to the same problem for Ionic 2? I'm facing the same problem as described in the question above,