# Ionic 2: Local notifications on click event executed multiple times

Tags: cordova, notifications, ionic2, cordova-plugins, localnotification

I have tried to implement local notification in Ionic 2. I followed every steps mentioned in the documentation. And it's working as well. But I'm having the problem on `click` event.

I found the same type of problem in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33511823/local-notification-schedule-and-trigger-methods-are-executing-multiple-times?answertab=active#tab-top) as well. But the solution is of Ionic 1.

My problem goes like this:

When I schedule any reminder/local notification, It gets registered. And when I keep on adding the reminder, It gets added as well. But when it comes to get the notification, I am facing the problem. When I click on the first notification, I get the desired output. But when I schedule the next notification and click on it. I get the output twice. The same thing happens if I set the multiple notification. i.e. If I schedule two or more than two notification, I get the same number of alert messages on click event of notification. The sample code I used is here:

Constructor:

`notifications:any;`

```js
 constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
                  public alertCtrl: AlertController,
                  private localNotifications: LocalNotifications,
                  public platform: Platform,
                  public loadingCtrl: LoadingController,
                  public navParams: NavParams) {

          this.platform.ready().then((readySource) => {
           this.localNotifications.on('click', (notification, state) =>{

                  let eventData = JSON.parse(notification.data);

                  let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
                    title: 'Reminder',
                    message: 'You have a notification of  '+eventData.data+'. Please click below to see details. ',
                    buttons: [
                      {
                        text: 'OK',
                        handler: () => {
                          this.cancelReminder(notification.id);
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  });
                  alert.present();
                });
        });
      }
```

Adding the Reminder and other method:

```js
addReminder(reminderId, displayMessage) {

    let loader = this.loadingCtrl.create({
      content: "Setting up Reminder..."
    });
    loader.present();

    this.localNotifications.getAllScheduled().then(data=> {
      this.notifications = data;
      let notification = {
        id: reminderId,
        title: 'Reminder Notification',
        text: 'Notification Head',
        at: new Date(new Date().getTime() + 60 * 1000),
        data: {
          data: displayMessage
        }
      }
      this.notifications.push(notification);
      this.localNotifications.clearAll().then(clearData => {
        loader.dismiss().catch(() => {
        });
        this.localNotifications.schedule(this.notifications);

      });
    });

    }

    cancelReminder(eventId) {
    this.localNotifications.cancel(eventId).then( ()=> {
      this.navCtrl.setRoot(Page);
    });
  }
```

Is there any mistake in the code? Or Is there another method to implement it?

Comment: try out this plugin - https://github.com/DavidBriglio/cordova-plugin-local-notifications which is forked from the original plugin. i guess updating the notification is refiring the notification in your case

Comment: It sounds like a problem with to many event-Listeners. So try to replace *this.localNotifications.on('click',* with *this.localNotifications.one('click',* . The reason is, that on will get called multiple times but one will propagate only once. Give it a try ;)

Comment: Property 'once' does not exist on type 'LocalNotifications'. Can you please guide on how to fix this issue.